# Java float and double diff

Tags: java

I am using jdk 1.6. This is my code.

```
float f = 10.0f;

double d = 10.0; 

System.out.println("Equal Status : " + (f == d));
```

then the system shows the answer as `true`.  But if I modified the value as

```
float f = 10.1f; 

double d = 10.1; 

System.out.println("Equal Status : " + (f == d));
```

then the system shows the answer as false. I know the system use Bit matching for == checking. But what is the reason behind. Can you explain about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: .1 cannot be represented with finite significant digits in binary representation, like how 1/3 cannot be represented with finite significant digits in decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not "my" answer, this is about as close to "must read" literature for programmers who want to move from "meh" to "good." Great is something truly special, so don't think that "good" is anything to sneeze at. :)

[What Every Programmer Needs to know about Floating Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

The link @Sam suggested is great but still too technical for me  :P

I will just give some opinions to OP for handling floating point (probably a bit off-topic because you are asking for the reason behind.  For the reason behind, read the link @Sam suggested).

Never assume floating point number is going to give you accurate representations.  Sometimes it can but not always.  Floating point has its constraint in "significant figures" which it is "accurate" for the first n-th digit.

Your situation is even worse cause you are mixing float and double, but the idea to solve is similar.

You need to decide to what precision your application needs the calculation result to be, and decide an Epsilon value base on it.  For example, your application needs only accuracy to 3 decimal place, probably a Epsilon of 0.0005 is reasonable.

Comparing two floating point number shouldn't be done by `==`, you should use 
`(a + EPSILON > b && a - EPSILON < b)`.  Similarly, `a > b` should be expressed as `a - EPSILON > b`

Comment: HA! No argument there. :) I don't grok all the points, to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Points to remember are

1. 10.1 is a repeating sequence in binary 1010101010......
2. When comparing a float and a double the float is converted to a
   double by adding zerro's to fill the number out

   so you will be comparing

   1010101...00000000...  to 1010101.....101010...   which are different.

   float f = 10.1f;

   double d = 10.1;

   System.out.println("Equal Status : " + (f == (float)d));

will give the answer of true

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, Generally speaking for 99% of use case `double` is a better choice because it is more accurate. i.e. don't use `float` unless you have to.

BigDecimal can be used to display the actual representation of a `float` or `double`. You don't see this normally as the `toString` will perform a small amount of rounding (as it is coded to accomodate the types representation limitations)

```
System.out.println("10.1f is actually " + new BigDecimal(10.1f));
System.out.println("10.1 is actually " + new BigDecimal(10.1));
```

prints

```
10.1f is actually 10.1000003814697265625
10.1 is actually 10.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
```

You can see that the `double` value is closer to the desired 10.1 but is not exactly this value.  The reason the values are different is that in each case, it have the closest resprentable value for that type.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is a 32 bit type whereas `double` is a 64 bit type.

You ran into the classical floating point precision problem.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are imprecise.  The actual values of 10.1f and 10.1 will be slightly different due to rounding. Floats are binary, not decimal, so numbers that look "simple" to us, like 10.1, can't be represented exactly as floats.

Comment: @Ned---You said actual values of 10.0f and 10.0 will be different, but according to OP it is showing true, which means they are same. SO this is not a proper reason to his question.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to refresh yourself on the [IEEE floating point standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for both 32 and 64-bit floating point representations.  If you peel into the internals of this, you'll see clearly as to why these floating points behave finicky.

If you're curious about how it's represented internally (which is why it's failing), you can use this code, which shows the hexadecimal representations of these numbers.  From there, you can match them up with the exponents and mantissas of single and double precision.

```
System.out.printf("Float 10.0: 0x%X\n", Float.floatToRawIntBits((float)10.0));
System.out.printf("Double 10.0: 0x%X\n", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(10.0));
System.out.printf("Float 10.1: 0x%X\n", Float.floatToRawIntBits((float)10.1));
System.out.printf("Double 10.1: 0x%X\n", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(10.1));
```

prints

```
Float 10.0: 0x41200000
Double 10.0: 0x4024000000000000
Float 10.1: 0x4121999A
Double 10.1: 0x4024333333333333
```

You'll notice that there is some repetition in the way the values are represented.  This is because 1/10 [can't be represented in a finite space of base 2](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).